Pyrogram Error on Google Colab [RuntimeError: This event loop is already running]
When I try to use pyrogram on Colab always get this error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-18-c2e1d12dd695> in <cell line: 8>()
      6 app = Client("my_account", api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)
      7 
----> 8 app.run()

2 frames

/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py in _check_running(self)
    582     def stop(self):
    583         """Stop running the event loop.
--> 584 
    585         Every callback already scheduled will still run.  This simply informs
    586         run_forever to stop looping after a complete iteration.

RuntimeError: This event loop is already running

My code is:
from pyrogram import Client

api_id = 123
api_hash = ""

app = Client("my_account", api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)

app.run()

In my computer runs well, but I don't want to use pyrogram local
